# ffmpeg less verbose, without hiding progress bar

Tags: ffmpeg, pipe, buffer, stderr, progress-bar

Without editing and recompiling `ffmpeg` from source, how can one hide some of the many lines that it prints when it **starts** encoding, without also hiding its progress bar that updates every second or so **while** encoding?

Progress bar:
`frame=14759 fps=3226 … bitrate=8509.2kbits/s speed= 108x`

Typical command:
`ffmpeg -hide_banner in.mov out.mp4`

Typical noise: a dozen or more lines like

```
  Duration: 00:59:19.45, start: 0.257200, bitrate: 9623 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
    Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m, bottom first), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:2[0xa0]: Audio: pcm_dvd, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (pcm_dvd (native) -> ac3 (native))
```

These attempts hide `Stream`, but also hide the progress bar (because it never reaches `egrep`, because of `\r` instead of `\n`?):

`stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 ( ffmpeg … 2>&1 ) | grep -v Stream`

`unbuffer ffmpeg … | unbuffer grep -v Stream`

Replace grep with something inherently unbuffered?
`sed -u /Stream/d` hides the progress bar, too.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465619/how-to-make-output-of-any-shell-command-unbuffered

Really complicated possible approach: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330636/how-to-grep-in-real-time-an-output-containing-a-progress-bar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -v quiet -stats -i in.mov out.mp4
```

No need to use `-hide_banner` flag.

Comment: The banner is apparently considered to be `info`, because it is hidden by `-v warning` or any quieter level, and it appears when `-v info` or any noisier level.  The manpage doesn't mention this, though.  Good find!

Answer (score 5):

Lower loglevel to `warning`/`24` but hide banner and expressly enable stats.

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -v warning -stats -i in.mov out.mp4
```